# MySql - Increment according to another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table (innoDB) that has 3 columns: ID, ID_FATHER, ROWPOS. ID is auto_increment and ROWPOS has values from other table. I need ID_FATHER to be incremented by 1 if ROWPOS is not a sequence, if it is a sequence ID_FATHER should not increment.

Like this:

```
ID | ID_FATHER | ROWPOS

1  |    1      | 250            
2  |    2      | 253
3  |    2      | 254
4  |    3      | 260
5  |    4      | 263
6  |    5      | 268
7  |    6      | 270
8  |    6      | 271
9  |    6      | 272
10 |    7      | 276
```

Is there a way to do that?

With this query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (i, rowpos)
SELECT @i := IF(t.rowpos = @prev_rowpos + 1, @i, @i + 1) AS i
     , @prev_rowpos := t.rowpos AS rowpos
  FROM temp
  JOIN (SELECT @prev_rowpos := NULL, @i := 0) v
 ORDER BY t.rowpos
```

I am able to import into the tables I want. But the problem is in the TABLE.Service, as you can see with this solution the ID_FATHER is wrong because it only increments by 1
but in this case it actually should be 2 because invoice 1 doesn't have service.

How can I solve this problem without changing all my schema.

```
TABLE.temp

ROW|TYPE |INVOICE_temp 
 1 |xxx  |10
 2 |xxP  |led tv
 3 |xxP  |mp3 Player
 4 |xxx  |11
 5 |xxP  |tv cable
 6 |xxS  |install

xxx = Invoice number
xxP = Product
xxs = service

TABLE.Invoice_Number             TABLE.Product                 

ID|ID_FATHER|ROWPOS|NUM    ID|ID_FATHER|ROWPOS|PROD        
1 |    1    | 1    | 10    1 |   1     |  2   | led tv                  
2 |    2    | 4    | 11    2 |   1     |  3   | mp3 player  
                           3 |   2     |  5   | tv cable

TABLE.Service

ID|ID_FATHER|ROWPOS|SERV
1 |    1    |   6  | install
```

I made some changes in the query to work as I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (i, rowpos)
SELECT @i := IF(t.rowpos = @prev_rowpos + 1, @i, @i + 1) AS i
     , @prev_rowpos := t.rowpos AS rowpos
  FROM another_table t
  JOIN (SELECT @prev_rowpos := NULL, @i := 0) v
 ORDER BY t.rowpos
```

(Test just the SELECT query, get that working returning the resultset you want, before you preface it with the INSERT.)

---

For completeness, I will add that this technique is dependent on UNDOCUMENTED and non-guaranteed behavior in MysQL, using "user variables".  I've successfully used this approach many times, but for "one off" type admin functions, not ever embedded as SQL in an application.

Note that the ORDER of the expressions in the SELECT list is important, they are evaluated in the order they appear in the SELECT list. (MySQL doesn't guarantee this behavior, but we do observe it. It's important that the check of the user variables containing values from the previous row to *precede* the assignment of the current row values to the user variables. That's why `i` is returned first, followed by `rowpos`. If you reversed the order of those in the SELECT list, the query would operate differently, and we wouldn't get the same results.

The purpose of the inline view (aliased as `v`) is to initialize the user variables. Since MySQL materializes that view query into a "derived table" before the outer query runs, those variables get initialized before they are referenced in the outer query. We don't really care what the inline view query actually returns, except that we need it to return exactly one row (because we reference it in a JOIN operation to the table we really want to query).

Comment: It worked perfectly but I found another problem with this, as shown above. Would you have an idea to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,rowpos INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (rowpos) VALUES
(250),
(253),
(254),
(260),
(263),
(268),
(270),
(271),
(272),
(276);


SELECT x.*
     , @i:=@i+ISNULL(y.id) i 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id < x.id 
   AND y.rowpos = x.rowpos - 1
     , (SELECT @i:=0) vals 
 ORDER  
    BY x.id;
+----+--------+------+
| id | rowpos | i    |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |    250 |    1 |
|  2 |    253 |    2 |
|  3 |    254 |    2 |
|  4 |    260 |    3 |
|  5 |    263 |    4 |
|  6 |    268 |    5 |
|  7 |    270 |    6 |
|  8 |    271 |    6 |
|  9 |    272 |    6 |
| 10 |    276 |    7 |
+----+--------+------+
```